# DateTime comparison logic

Tags: c#, date

I was playing around with code for conversion of `DateTime`to `long` and viceversa.
I found an interesting observation. Below is my code :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(123456);
int isEqual  = DateTime.Compare(dt.ToLocalTime(), DateTime.MinValue.ToLocalTime());
if (isEqual == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date is Equal");
}
```

I debugged and check both the value,

```
dt is {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

and

```
DateTime.MinValue is also {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

I am wondering then why `isEqual` value is `1` rather than `0`.

When compared both the values `using string.Equals()` method; it returned `false`.

Need a Rationale.

Comment: What's confusing you? If `Compare` returns `1`, it means that the first parameter is *greater* than the second one. `Compare` returns `0` if the two parameters are equal. `new DateTime(123456)` is indeed greater than `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: Don't use dt for DataTime.Most people use dt for a DataTable.

Comment: will keep in mind.

Comment: Try `dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff")` and note that it's 0.0123456 seconds later than `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score -1):

DateTime object uses Ticks property of DateTime object to compare 2 DateTime objects.

As per MS Docs :

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond (see TicksPerMillisecond) and 10 million ticks in a second.

So to see difference in date object even at seconds level your tick value should be greater than 10 million. So till you pass a number less than 10000000 you won't see difference in date string between the DateTime.MinValue and the DateTime object you create by passing ticks to the constructor.
In case you didn't realize, the constructor you are using passing in single Int64, takes it as number of ticks.

Refer to MS Docs for more detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0

TL;DR;
DateTime object uses Ticks property of DateTime object to compare 2 DateTime objects. So as the number of ticks are different so isEqual is 1 but because the difference between ticks is less than 10 million you don't see it on date time string. Try querying Ticks property to know why compareTo is returning 1.

Answer (score -1):

> I am wondering then why isEqual value is 1 rather than 0.

Simply because `new DateTime(123456)` represents a `DateTime` that is `123456` ticks greater than `DateTime.MinValue`.

`new DateTime()` (without any ticks), which is also the default value for a `DateTime`, is the only value that is truly equal to `DateTime.MinValue`:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
int isEqual = DateTime.Compare(dt.ToLocalTime(), DateTime.MinValue.ToLocalTime());
if (isEqual == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date is Equal");
}
```

When you watch the value of a `DateTime` in the debugger, you don't see the `Ticks` part by default. But it you expand the variable, you'll notice that it's there:

[image]

Comment: @NishantKumar: Does this answer your question or what's left to it?